# Вынести за пределы карты кастомный поиск для яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Делаю форму заявки для сайта по доставке еды. Нужно сделать аналогично как у сайта ДоДо Пицца. Я почти все сделал, при вводе в input появляются подсказки, но не появляется список найденных вариантов адресов. Например, я вводу для города Москва в поиск "Арбат", я выбираю в подсказке "Москва, улица Арбат", но родной поиска карты выдает дополнительный список результата поиска: "Улица Арбат" и "улица Новый Арбат". Вот добавить такой список для своего кастомного поля поиска не знаю как.

```
<input type="text" id="suggest" name="address" placeholder="город, улица, дом" autocomplete="off">
<div id="map-delivery"></div>

// JS
ymaps.ready(init);


function init() {
  const searchInput = document.getElementById("#suggest");


  const center = [55.884216, 37.689635];
// Создание карты
  let myMap = new ymaps.Map('map-delivery', {
      center,
      zoom: 10,
      controls: ['geolocationControl']
    });

// Добавление поля поиска на карту
  let searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
      noPlacemark: true,
      placeholderContent: 'Введите адрес или место',
      provider: 'yandex#search',
    }
  });
    myMap.controls.add(searchControl);

    // Стилизация метки для результата поиска
    const deliveryPoint = new ymaps.GeoObject({
      geometry: {type: 'Point'},
      properties: {iconCaption: 'Адрес'}
    }, {
      preset: 'islands#blackDotIconWithCaption',
      draggable: true,
      iconCaptionMaxWidth: '215'
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(deliveryPoint);

   // Функция поиска: взять текст адреса из кастомного поиска, вставить в родной поиск карты, найти адрес
  function search () {
    let request = searchInput.value;
    searchControl.search(request);
  };

// Добавление подсказок для кастомного поиска
 const suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest');

suggestView.events.add('select', search);

}
```

На скрине показан выпадающий список результата поиска (не подсказки), который мне как раз нужно реализовать для кастомного поля поиска адреса.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка при объявлении константы **searchInput**. Уберите решётку из строкового значения **"#suggest"**, чтобы скрипт знал, откуда брать **value**:

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById("suggest");
```

Comment: спасибо, у меня в коде без ошибок, здесь случайно добавил

Comment: Тогда в чём проблема? С корректной инициализацией API ваш скрипт нормально работает. Или вопрос уже решён? Если нет, можете собрать пример на jsbin.com ?